# How to execute a method of a class from another class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am very new in Java Swing development and I have the following problem:

I have this `GUI` class that contains the `main()` method:

```
package com.test.login3;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;


public class GUI extends SingleFrameApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(GUI.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("GUIBis ---> startUp()");
        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("Entered into GUI ---> shutdown()"); 
    }

}
```

As you can see in this class there is the `main()` method that simply performs this operation:

```
launch(GUI.class, args);
```

Reading on the official documentation: [launch doc](http://bellquel.bo.cnr.it/appframework/org/jdesktop/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

> Creates an instance of the specified Application subclass, sets the
>   ApplicationContext application property, and then calls the new
>   Application's startup method. The launch method is typically called
>   from the Application's main. The applicationClass constructor and
>   startup methods run on the event dispatching thread.

So the `startup()` method is executed and there is created and show a new `MainFrame` object

2) This is the MainFrame code (it extends a classic Swing JFrame):

```
package com.test.login3;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.test.login.LoginFrame;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final int FIXED_WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final Dimension INITAL_SIZE = new Dimension(FIXED_WIDTH, 620);

    public MainFrame() {
        super();

        setPreferredSize(INITAL_SIZE);
        setResizable(false);

        setTitle("My Application");
        setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));

        JButton logOutButton = new JButton("LogOut");

        logOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // Execute when button is pressed:
                System.out.println("You clicked the button");

            }
        });   

        add(logOutButton);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        // Center the window

    }


}
```

My problem is this:

As you can see in the `GUI.java` class, a `shutdown()` method is definied (that is defined in the `SingleFrameApplication` abstact class). Here is the documentation for this method: [shutdown doc](http://bellquel.bo.cnr.it/appframework/org/jdesktop/application/SingleFrameApplication.html#shutdown%28%29)

Reading the documentation:

> Save session state for the component hierarchy rooted by the mainFrame.

When the user clicks on the `JButton` that is declared inside the `MainFrame` class, I would like the `shutdown()` method (that is declared into the `GUI` class) to be executed.

Do you have a solution to implement this behavior?

Thank you

Andrea

Comment: The first thing that you need is MainFrame to actually know about your GUI object. For that, you probably want to pass the GUI object ("this") as an argument to the MainFrame's constructor, where you can then save it to a field in MainFrame. You can then use an event listener or other technique to call the shutdown method on the MainFrame's GUI instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PropertyChanges. Have GUI implement PropertyChangeListener. Then have MainFrame fire a property change when the button is clicked. In GUI, this property change is caught and the shut-down command is executed. See [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) for more info.

Something like:

in class GUI:

```
public class GUI extends SingleFrameApplication implements PropertyChangeListener {
```

...

```
MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
mainFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
```

...

```
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getPropertyName().equals("buttonClicked")) {
        shutdown();
    }
}
```

Then in MainFrame

```
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // Execute when button is pressed:
            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
            firePropertyChange("buttonClicked", false, true);
        }
```

Comment: mmm I have added a PropertyChangeListener in my GUI classs, what have I to do to fire a property change when the user click on the button?